# Is GSS currently deployable?

Tags: css

I saw a website last week outlining grid style sheets, a new alternative to CSS. From what I recall, it seemed like a much needed upgrade for front end web developers. That being said, I do not recall seeing documentation on how to implement it (css includes?) or anything of the sort.

So my question is: Is GSS readily usable for developers? Can one opt to use it instead of CSS today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled for GSS and there seems to be documentation on the website http://gridstylesheets.org/demos/hello-world/

That being said, the hello world program (http://bit.ly/1GLteuQ) does not look production ready since the Hello on the top gets cropped when the height of the bottom window is small enough to introduce a scroll bar. So I don't think you should use it on websites before it matures enough.

Comment: Please don’t use link shorteners to try to get around filters. Actually include the code like it suggests.

Comment: @minitech The question did not require any code solution, it required a yes/no answer and copy pasting all the code would make no sense since it wasn't relavant anyway. The codepen link is from the hello world sample only